# One ViewModel for Multiple Pages

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, action, viewmodel

I have a View Model attached with Multiple Pages. I have also Commands on different controls bound to properties in this ViewModel.

How Do I know the Command in ViewModel is called from which control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you don't need to know the source. But there are always solutions for each state :)
You may use a property in your viewModel such as

```
public UIElement Owner {get;set;}
//if(Owner.GetType() ...do bla bla
```

Or you may use CommandParameter

```
CommandParameter="123" ; CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

But I think if we need to know the source control,something may missing in our design. But some conditions I agree this can be a need.

There is no way of getting action source as shown in java code below,we don't interest in the source object with this concept. Maybe models or part of your models behavior should run uncommon.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
...
Object source = e.getItemSelectable();

if (source == chinButton) {
    //...make a note of it...
} else if (source == glassesButton) {
    //...make a note of it...
} else if (source == hairButton) {
    //...make a note of it...
} else if (source == teethButton) {
    //...make a note of it...
}
```